# How can I draw border tightly around 2 controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a ToggleButton which control a Popup similar to ComboBox. I want to draw a border like TabItems that flows around the button and popup when popup is visible and just around the button when it is invisible.

Answer (score 1):

A PopUp by definition pops up over the existing content, so drawing a border around both a PopUp and the button isn't really an option. What about using an Expander instead?

Comment: Can I draw borders partially? I can give the effect in that case.

Comment: Sure, BorderThickness can be set for left, top, right, bottom individually, e.g. BorderThickness="5,5,0,0"

Comment: I mean since button is small, I need border on top to be 20 less in length.

Comment: I do not entirely agree with your statement Colin. In some cases, you might want to do it. ex: a comboBox is a toggleButton + a popup, but you might want your comboBox to be styled so that when opened, it looks like a single control (a bit like a listBox), with a border going over both the toggle Button AND the popup.